# Height div from top to bottom of page color trouble

Tags: html, css, height

i have searched a response here but i don't find a solution...

i have a problem with div height.
i explain myself : I have one menu to the top of the page with a fixed weight : 50px.

i have a MainDiv which is the principal div with min-height : 100%. I already have put Height:100% to html and body. My problem is the background-color of my MainDiv doesn't go from the top to the bottom of the page. I know it's because i have a fixed height with my menu but i don't understand how to change that..

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
    background-image: url('../../Images/fond2.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-position: left top;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

#menuBackground {
    background:#2f3036;
    text-align: center;
    width : 100%;
    height : 50px;
    display : relative;
}

#MainDiv{
    max-width:850px;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color:#E0CDA9;
    display : absolute;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

look my fiddle project : http://jsfiddle.net/hr8sL/5925/

i just want to get background color filled the page (without the top menu of course).

Edit : i have tried to use overflow : auto. It works BUT the scrollbar is positionned on the div. I want to keep the scrollbar on the entire page.

Answer (score 0):

try this: you have a mistake in `#menuBackground {display : relative;}`.

Change it to `#menuBackground {display : inline-block;}`